# libxml2-Question about xmlCreateFileParserCtxt

Tags: c, libxml2, address-sanitizer

I'm confused about the return value. I think the `ret` is a newly allocated memory, and I need to free it by using `xmlFreeParserCtxt`. But when I remove `xmlFreeParserCtxt`, I found there is no error and I'm sure the ret value is not NULL!(I use `-fsanitize=address` to detect)
If the ret value  of `xmlCreateFileParserCtxt` is not `NULL`, is it possible that it isn't newly allocated?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>
#include <libxml/xmlwriter.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>
#include <libxml/parserInternals.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLtree.h>
#include <libxml/xinclude.h>
#include <libxml/catalog.h>
#include <libxml/uri.h>
#include <libxml/valid.h>
#include <libxml/xmlsave.h>
#include <libxml/nanoftp.h>
#include <libxml/schemasInternals.h>
#include <libxml/relaxng.h>
#include <libxml/xmlschemas.h>
#include <libxml/dict.h>
#include <libxml/pattern.h>
#include <libxml/hash.h>
#include <libxml/xmlversion.h>

int main() {
    const char* xmlFilePath = "example.xml";

    // Create a parser context for parsing an XML file
    xmlParserCtxtPtr ctxt = xmlCreateFileParserCtxt(xmlFilePath);
    if (ctxt == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create parser context for file: %s\n", xmlFilePath);
        return 1;
    }


    // Cleanup
    // xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);

    return 0;
}
```

First, I add the `xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);`, I'm sure there is no error msg. And then, I delete this line. I compile this code by: `gcc ./test.c -g -lxml2 -fsanitize=address`. I think I should got error output, but nothing happened. No memleaks!

Comment: Don't tag C code with C++

Comment: @273K I just edit the tag. Sorry...